# multiple angular 17 http get request not happening in the network

Tags: node.js, angular, express, httpclient, angular17

After upgrade to angular 17 the HttpClient looks to cache http GETs and just runs it once.

[multiple calls to the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFjPU.png)

I expected to see more requests in the network but actually it just shows up the first request.
All subscribes to the httpClient Observable shows the same first result.

my app.config

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      routes,
      // withPreloading(PreloadAllModules),
      // withDebugTracing(),
      withComponentInputBinding(),
      withRouterConfig({
        paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always',
      })
    ),
    importProvidersFrom(
      BrowserModule,
      LightboxModule,
      OverlayModule,
      SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
      MatDialogModule,
      MatSnackBarModule,
      provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
      provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient],
        },
      })
    ),
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi(), withFetch()), // withInterceptors([relativePathInterceptor])
    provideStore(),
    provideEffects(),
    isDevMode() ? provideStoreDevtools() : [],
    provideClientHydration(),
  ],
};
```

this is my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "sugar": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/sugar",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development2": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "sugar:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "sugar:build:development2"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "sugar:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "2d1ee5f9-3a66-4408-b599-05e081007ab2"
  }
}
```

my chat.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Conversation } from './interfaces/user.interface';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ChatService {
  withCredentials = environment.withCredentials;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getInbox(): Observable<Array<Conversation>> {
    // const url = `${environment.baseUrl}/api/chat/inbox?t=` + Date.now();
    const url = `${environment.baseUrl}/api/chat/inbox`;

    return this.http.get<Array<Conversation>>(url, {
      withCredentials: this.withCredentials,
      transferCache: false,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Are you using SSR ?

Comment: Yes I am using SSR by default

Comment: You should share your chat service code.

Comment: my chat service is shared